# MySQL Sub Records

Tags: mysql

ok so I´ve been trying to retrieve a group of sub records from a main record. I'm making a simple exam app and want to retrieve the answers from a question.

I have the following tables:

```
Questions:

--------------------------------------------------
| question_id | exam_id | question               |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1           | 1       | What's 2+2?            |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2           | 1       | What's 6+5?            |
--------------------------------------------------

Answers:

--------------------------------------------------
| answer_id | question_id  | answer              |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1         | 1            | 4                   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2         | 1            | 10                  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 3         | 2            | 11                  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 4         | 2            | 15                  |
--------------------------------------------------

I want to output:

--------------------------------------------------
| question_id | question       | answers         |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1           | What's 2+2?    | 4,10            |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2           | What's 6+5?    | 11,15           |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I'm trying to use the following query but it doesn't return anything:

```
SELECT 
    questions.question_id,
    questions.question,
    GROUP_CONCAT(answers.answer) as answers

FROM questions, answers

WHERE questions.exam_id = 1 AND answers.question_id = questions.question_id 

GROUP BY questions.question_id
```

Comment: [I don't see any errors with the query.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/036411/13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
GROUP BY questions.question_id
```

by

```
GROUP BY answers.question_id;
```

Comment: It still returns an empty row. :/

Comment: Haha it worked, I had a nooby error. Thanks for the help! :)